# How to identify i-frame from idr-frame in the ffprobe show frames output?

Tags: ffmpeg, keyframes

The ffprobe show frames output shows the following details:

```
[FRAME]
media_type=video
key_frame=1
pkt_pts=42
pkt_pts_time=0:00:00.042000
pkt_dts=42
pkt_dts_time=0:00:00.042000
pkt_duration=N/A
pkt_duration_time=N/A
pkt_pos=799
width=1920
height=1080
pix_fmt=yuv420p
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
pict_type=I
coded_picture_number=0
display_picture_number=0
interlaced_frame=0
top_field_first=0
repeat_pict=0
reference=3
[/FRAME]
```

I was reading [this article](http://www.streaminglearningcenter.com/articles/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-idr-frames-but-were-afraid-to-ask.html) and was wondering how to differentiate between the two types of frames from the above output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Frames with key_frame `1` (will have picture type `I`) are IDR frames.

`I` frames with key_frame `0` are not.

Comment: It [doesn't seem to work exactly like that](https://superuser.com/questions/1344558/ffprobe-returns-that-all-i-frames-are-idr-frames-keyframe-1-in-a-ts-file) -- non-IDR frames with the Recovery Point SEI set are also reported as keyframes

Comment: Those types aren't common unless you work with transport feeds.

Comment: I'm working a lot with .MTS files from JVC camcorders; they're full of them. But indeed I have no knowledge on how much they appear "in the wild"